# Checking for equality throughout each character of string

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a palindrome. I think I might be overthinking the solution with way too many conditional loops inside my if statement. I'm having trouble trying to update the while loop to check whether it has gone through and checked for equality throughout each character of the string, and to update it. Can someone point me in the right direction, and also how can I do a cleaner job with code?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();

        main.isPalindrome("saippuakivikauppias");
        main.isPalindrome("Hello World");
        main.isPalindrome("Was it a car or a cat I saw");
    }

    private boolean isPalindrome(String word) {

        int first = word.charAt(0);
        int last = word.charAt(word.length() - 1);

        if(word.length() <= 1) {
             return true;
        } else if(word.trim().length() > 1) {
            if(Character.isLetter(first) && Character.isLetter(last)) {
                while(first == last) {
                    first++;
                    last--;
                    //if loop to check if the while loop as gone through the entire string?
                    //update?
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }


        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is not correct. Not even close. `first++` and `last--` are not doing what you expect.

Comment: The while loop is where your code breaks down.  Honestly I would just start over on that part.  You want to loop halfway through the string.  Try using a for loop to go half the number of iterations as there are characters in the string (rounded up).  On each iteration, you can check if the corresponding character from the other end of the string matches.  Also, you can use the [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) method to get rid of whitespace characters *before* entering the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You really overthought this one - you should think a bit more basic about your problem:

A palindrome is a string that is the same read backward and forward -> create a reverse of `word` and compare to `word`

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word){
    StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(word).reverse();
    return word.equals(reverse.toString());
}
```

You could even do this - depending on your coding style - in one line.